# How to parse JSON using Alamofire in Swift 3.0 without any third-party library

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

Here I want to parse JSON via url. This is what actual JSON data available on url. So I need to parse it and read in my app using Alamofire. But I 'm unable to do it.

JSON Data in my url.

```
  {
        "main": [
        {
        "date": "2017-01-11",
        "USDARS": "15.8302",
        "USDCLP": "670.400024",
        "USDSDG": "6.407695"
        },
        {
        "date": "2017-01-12",
        "USDARS": "15.804999",
        "USDCLP": "661.599976",
        "USDSDG": "6.407697"
        },
        {
        "date": "2017-01-13",
        "USDARS": "15.839041",
        "USDCLP": "659.200012",
        "USDSDG": "6.407704"
        },
        {
        "date": "2017-01-14",
        "USDARS": "15.839041",
        "USDCLP": "659.200012",
        "USDSDG": "6.407704"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I read it using Alamofire in swift 3.0

Below is what actually I'm trying to parse above JSON data via url.

```
Alamofire.request("myurl") .responseJSON { response in

            print("In Alamofire")
            if let arr = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]
            {

                if let arr = response.result.value as? [NSDictionary]
                {
                    let val1 = (arr["main"]["USDARS"] as? String)
                    print(val1)
                    //It does not print any thing.
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help me. I'm new to it.

Comment: try arr["main"][0]["USDARS"], cause "main" is an array of objects.

Comment: Didn't you posted that SAME question a few days ago? I don't remember that you gave any change to your code following the previous comments or question. I reported previously: Why `if let arr = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject]` then `if let arr = response.result.value as? [NSDictionary]` It doesn't make sense, and you should prefer Swift Type to NSStuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Top level json is `[String:Any]` and main is an array i.e. `[[String:String]]`

```
    Alamofire.request("myurl") .responseJSON { response in
        if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any], 
           let main = result["main"] as? [[String:String]]{
           // main[0]["USDARS"] or use main.first?["USDARS"] for first index or loop through array
           for obj in main{
               print(obj["USDARS"])
               print(obj["date"])
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes it prints all values of 'USDARS' but how should I print only particular value or last value of 'obj'

Comment: for first .. simply you can get by `main.first?["USDARS"]` .. or give index like `main[0]["USDARS"]`

Comment: ok and if I want to get value for particular date then how should I do it?

Comment: use particular key .. for date `obj["date"]` .. for USDSDG `obj["USDSDG"]`

Comment: glad it helps  :)

Comment: Hello One more problem arises, I'm unable to typecast the value from String to NSNumber.

Comment: `let usdars = Double(obj["USDARS"])!`

Comment: Hello @EI Captain, can you help me in my new question which is similar to this. http://stackoverflow.com/q/42245848/7291053

Comment: It give main as nil

Comment: { key1: value1, key2 : [ { } ] }   I have this kind on json

Answer (score 0):

You should use [SwiftyJson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON), which is a library for json parsing, very usefull with Alamofire

In your case you can do something like this with swiftyJson :

```
//Array & Dictionary
var jsonArray: JSON =  [
   "main": ["date": "2017-01-11", "USDARS": "15.8302"]
]

let dateString = jsonArray["main"][0]["date"].string

print(dateString) = "2017-01-11"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @IBAction func btnget(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let urlpath : String = "http://202.131.123.211/UdgamApi_v4/App_Services/UdgamService.asmx/GetAllTeacherData?StudentId=2011111"

    let url = URL(string: urlpath)

    var urlrequest = URLRequest(url: url!)

    urlrequest.httpMethod = "GET"

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlrequest) { (data, response, error) in

        do {
            guard let getResponseDic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
                return
            }
            // now we have the todo, let's just print it to prove we can access it

            print(getResponseDic as NSDictionary)

            let dic = getResponseDic as NSDictionary
            let msg = dic.object(forKey: "message")

            print(dic)
            //let arrObj = dic.object(forKey: "teacherDetail") as! NSArray
            //print(arrObj)

            //let arr = dic.value(forKey: "TeacherName")as! NSArray

            print(((dic.value(forKey: "teacherDetail") as! NSArray).object(at: 0) as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "TeacherName") as! String)

            // the todo object is a dictionary
            // so we just access the title using the "title" key
            // so check for a title and print it if we have one

            // print("The title is: " + todoTitle)
        } catch  {
            print("error trying to convert data to JSON")
            return
        }
    } task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written